# Ruby add variables to an existing object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, attributes, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I add variables to an existing obejct?
I have a list of chat rooms and I want to add a new variable for each chat to use at my view:

Example I want to add total users of chat

```
def index
  chats_all = ChatRoom.all
  @chats = Array.new
  chats_all.each |chat|
    chat.total_users = 10
    @chats << chat
  end
  @chats
end
```

total_users is not an attribute of ChatRoom class.

**[EDIT - explaim better after @jvillian great awnser]**

I don't want total_users as an attribute of User class. 
I just want to add as a variable to use at this one single page. For json rails already let my add new attributes to objects. Just need to use as_json().map and a merge()
Example:

```
def index
  chats = chats.as_json().map {
    |chat| 
    chat.merge(
      total_users: 10
    }
  response = { chats: chats }
  render json: response
end
```

Now I got an json with chats and each chat has total_users attribute.

I want to know if I can do something like this with objects, just add a temporary variable to use at index page.

Comment: It does not sounds clear to me. What's the existing object? And what variable do you want to add? Maybe you can build an hash `@chats = {:'1' => {total_users: 10}, .... `. Can you explain more?

Comment: "total_users is not an attribute of ChatRoom class" - sounds like it should be.

Comment: How exactly are you using `total_users`? This seems like it might be an XY problem.

Comment: @jvillian I am using in my view. At my .html.erb file I have `@chats.each |chat|` and than I display total_users

Comment: But total users is always 10?

Comment: No, it's just an example

Comment: I guess you *could* do this but why is a pretty fair question. If you really still want to implement this I would suggest looking into `define_singleton_method` or `instance_eval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create temporary custom Objects without add new attributes to database Struct solve my problem.

I can create a Struct with chat room info and total users

```
chat_info = Struct.new(:name, :total_users, :messages)
chat_temp = []
chats = ChatRoom.where(condition)
chats.each do |chat|
  chat_temp << chat_info.new("nome", 100, messages)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
class ChatRoom < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :total_users
end
```

You can read more in the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor).

Then, index could look like:

```
def index
  @chats = ChatRoom.all.map do |chat|
    chat.total_users = 10
    chat
  end
end
```

Alternatively, I would be tempted to do something like:

```
class ChatRoom < ActiveRecord::Base
  TOTAL_USERS = 10

  attr_accessor :total_users

  def total_users
    @total_users || TOTAL_USERS
  end
end
```

And then:

```
def index 
  @chats = ChatRoom.all
end
```

Now, you'll get

```
@chats.first.total_users
 => 10
```

You can set `total_users` to something else if you like, but it will default to 10.

Here's a potential approach using OpenStruct:

```
def index
  @chats = ChatRoom.all.map do |chat|
    OpenStruct.new(
      chat.
        attributes.
        merge!(total_users: 10)
    )
  end
end
```

Now, you can do:

```
@chats.each do |chat|
  puts chat.total_users
end
```

which will return `10`.

BTW and TBH, I do something like that last sort of thing (using OpenStruct or custom decorators) *all the time*. In my more recent apps, views **never** have direct access to models.

Comment: Good solution. But now it's an attribute of the class. Isn't it?

Comment: @iGian but only a "virtual attribute" not an `attributes` attribute used for persistence purposes. And rails 5 has actually implemented an API for this with type specification [Nice Read](https://blog.metova.com/rails-5-attributes-api)

Comment: Thanks! I’ll take a look. I like this solution.

Comment: @jvillian thank you, but I don't want to add a new attribute to my class, I just want to add total_users to use at one single page. I will edit my question to explaim better. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to send the response to the view as an array and scan to show informations?

```
def index
  @chats = ChatRoom.all.as_json().map { |chat| chat.merge("total_users" => 10) }
end
```

Then access `@chats`, which is actually an array of hashes, view:

```
<% @chats.each do |chat| %>
  <p><%= chat["total_users"] %></p>
<% end %>
```

You can check how `@chats` is structured by `<p><%= @chats %></p>`

I maybe made some syntax error.